# Performing a CountIf in R in HUGE dataframe (Over 20 million rows)

Tags: r, dataframe, countif

I have a dataframe containing 600 codes (just like the one below) to match with a 28 million row dataframe. I want to see how many times each code in the first dataframe appear in the second dataframe (both have a column with the dataframes that match). It's basically a Countif (like an Excel),
See I have dataframe 1, example below: Codes in the dataframe 1 are unique, 600 unique codes, in dataframe 2 they will repeat.

```
| Code 4 Dig| Name           |
| --------  | -------------- |
| 0111      | Name 1         |
| 0894      | Name 2         |
| 7895      | Name 3         |
| 8412      | Name 4         |
```

The 28 million row's header is somewhat like this (ID is irrelevant to me just want to count how many times the codes from the first data appears):

```
| Code 4 Dig| ID             |
| --------  | -------------- |
| 0894      | ID152           |
| 0894      | ID 25           |
| 0894      | ID10            |
| 7895      | ID 125          |
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Inner join and look at number of rows per group. Use `data.table` for speed.

Comment: Use ‘table’ ont the long column and merge with the short one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

28M rows is not really HUGE for R. Can do it with base R, dplyr, or data.table.

I'll borrow the examples from jared_mamrot and show the speed in both dplyr and dtplyr (aka easier data.table).

dplyr code below takes about 6 seconds to run. Frankly, if this is a one time script or once a month script then I wouldn't bother speeding this up. If you are running this on demand for a customer and need the results in less than a second then continue to the dtplyr or data.table answer.

```
library(tidyverse)

pick.nums <- function(n) {
  floor(10^(sample(3:8, n, replace = TRUE))*runif(n))
}

df1 <- data.frame("Code 4 Dig" = c(pick.nums(600)),
                  "Name" = paste("name_", pick.nums(600), sep = ""),
                  check.names = FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame("Code 4 Dig" = c(pick.nums(28000000)),
                  "ID" = paste("ID_", c(pick.nums(28000000)), sep = ""),
                  check.names = FALSE)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark({
  result <- df1 %>% 
    inner_join(df2) %>% 
    group_by(`Code 4 Dig`) %>%
    summarise(count = n())
}, times = 3)
# Unit: seconds
#      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# 4.569945 5.466638 5.986419 6.363332 6.694656 7.025981     3

str(result)
tibble [437 x 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
$ Code 4 Dig: num [1:437] 7 9 38 59 79 88 91 100 103 105 ...
$ count     : int [1:437] 10556 5207 5175 5179 5145 5162 5248 5214 5228 5282 ...
```

If you need it to go really fast then the dtplyr method can do the join and count in 0.035 seconds. However, it does take 1.9 seconds to key the data before you do the join. So it still takes a couple seconds.

```
library(dtplyr)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
dt1 <- df1 %>% lazy_dt(key_by = `Code 4 Dig`),
dt2 <- df2 %>% lazy_dt(key_by = `Code 4 Dig`), 
times = 3)
# Unit: milliseconds
#         min         lq        mean    median          uq         max
#    1.039201    1.17975    1.575267    1.3203    1.843301    2.366301
# 1708.594001 1737.07515 1952.342434 1765.5563 2074.216651 2382.877001


microbenchmark::microbenchmark({
  resultdt <- dt1 %>% 
    inner_join(dt2) %>% 
    group_by(`Code 4 Dig`) %>%
    summarise(count = n()) %>%
    as_tibble()
}, times = 3)
# Unit: milliseconds
# min      lq    mean  median       uq     max neval
# 29.4548 32.8968 35.3977 36.3388 38.36915 40.3995     3

str(resultdt)
tibble [437 x 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
$ Code 4 Dig: num [1:437] 7 9 38 59 79 88 91 100 103 105 ...
$ count     : int [1:437] 10556 5207 5175 5179 5145 5162 5248 5214 5228 5282 ...
```

Comment: Note that John Spring's answer speeds things up by doing the counting before doing the joining. I'll leave that for you.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a dplyr approach. On my computer it takes about a second to run on 20M rows and 4-7 seconds for 200M rows.

```
library(dplyr)

big_table %>%                # take the big table
  count(code) %>%            # count how many appearances of each code
  left_join(lookup_table)    # join those counts to orig table to get `Name`
                             # note: any code not in lookup_table would show NA for `Name`
```

source data:

```
lookup_table <- data.frame(code = 1:600,
                           names = paste("Name", 1:600))

big_table <- lookup_table %>%
  mutate(times = rpois(n(), 34000)) %>%     # random times for each row  
  uncount(times) %>%                        # copy row this many times
  slice_sample(n = nrow(.))                 # to shuffle
```

Answer (score 1):

#### This is basically the answer that @Gregor-Thomas gave in his comment

Without posting your own attempts to solve the problem, I can only guess whether this solution will suit your use case.

```r
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

# Create example data
df1 <- tibble::tribble(
~"Code 4 Dig",           ~"Name",
"0111",         "Name 1",
"0894",         "Name 2",
"7895",         "Name 3",
"8412",         "Name 4"
  )

df2 <- tibble::tribble(
~"Code 4 Dig",             ~"ID",
"0894",          "ID152",
"0894",          "ID 25", 
"0894",           "ID10",
"7895",         "ID 125"
  )

# Convert example dataframes to data.tables
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

# Set keys for joining
setkey(df1, `Code 4 Dig`)
setkey(df2, `Code 4 Dig`)

# Join the tables
Result <- df1[df2, nomatch=0]

# Summarise to get counts
counts <- Result[, .(counts = .N), by = `Code 4 Dig`]
counts
#>    Code 4 Dig counts
#> 1:       0894      3
#> 2:       7895      1
```

--

And, to show it works with 600 numbers (df1) and 28M rows (df2):

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

# Create example data
pick.nums <- function(n) {
  floor(10^(sample(3:8, n, replace = TRUE))*runif(n))
}

pick.nums(5)
#> [1] 52198541  8972430    98870      720  4013067

df1 <- data.frame("Code 4 Dig" = c(pick.nums(600)),
                  "Name" = paste("name_", pick.nums(600), sep = ""),
                  check.names = FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame("Code 4 Dig" = c(pick.nums(28000000)),
                  "ID" = paste("ID_", c(pick.nums(28000000)), sep = ""),
                  check.names = FALSE)

# Convert example dataframes to data.tables
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

# Set keys for joining
setkey(df1, `Code 4 Dig`)
setkey(df2, `Code 4 Dig`)

# Join the tables
Result <- df1[df2, nomatch=0]

# Summarise to get counts
counts <- Result[, .(counts = .N), by = `Code 4 Dig`]
counts
#>      Code 4 Dig counts
#>   1:          9   5166
#>   2:         13   5122
#>   3:         24   5193
#>   4:         25   5198
#>   5:         30   5227
#>  ---                  
#> 437:    8841332      1
#> 438:    8966071      2
#> 439:    8969648      1
#> 440:    9040953      1
#> 441:    9591721      1
```